# Store multiple ID's in the same column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sqldatatypes

Is it possible to store an array of ID's within a table column which reference ID's from another table so that I can do a select query and determine whether a specific ID is within that column?

Example scenario below.

I have 3 tables like this:

```
Table: tab_groups with Columns: id, name
Table: tab_users with Columns: id, name, groups
Table: tab_forums with Columns: id, title, req_groups
```

A user can belong to multiple groups, the ID's of the groups that they belong to are stored in the `groups` column.

A forum can have multiple required groups specified, which the ID's of are stored in `req_groups`. A user must belong to at least 1 group which matches with at least 1 required group in order to view the forum.

How should I store the `groups` and `req_groups` columns so that I can later do a SELECT query to check whether a user belongs to a group which matches with a group ID required to view the forum?

Also how would I update those columns to include new ID's or remove old ones?

Currently I just have a pretty inefficient method which involves storing them as a string with a separator (like 1,2,3,4), then splitting them in PHP and doing a comparison check in a loop.

For updating I just check whether a value exists, and add it onto the string.

Comment: You create another table called `UserGroup` with one row per user and one row per group assigned to them.  This is called a junction table.  Do not store the values in a single column.

Comment: Don't store data like that, will only cause you problems...

Comment: Please take Gordon and Jarl's advice. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of questions on Stack Overflow where programmers thought it was a good idea to store multiple values in a single column and find themselves wrestling with increasingly desperate, esoteric, and unmanageable queries.

Comment: You may want to read up on [database normalization](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Database+normalization), specifically [junction tables](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=junction+table+sql)

Comment: Would I need to create two junction tables? One for the relationship between users and groups, and another for the relationship between forums and groups?